# Workflow Manager Get-WFFarm error

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-server, workflow-manager

We have dedicated WF Farm (3 WF Servers - WF1, WF2, WF3) for our SharePoint environment. The WF certificate was expired. So we have panned to update the WF certificate steps are followed by this reference [URL](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/microsoft-sharepoint-blog/sharepoint-2013-2016-2019-how-to-replace-expired-workflow/ba-p/1148650). I have changed the server time as mention in the 1st step. then while proceeding 2nd step "Get-WFFarm" cmdlet threw an exception "The type initializer for "**System.Data.SQLClient.SQLConnection Configuring system failed to initialize**"  only in WF1 server on other 2 servers (WF2 and WF3) this cmdlet was ran successfully without exception. 
 
 Can anyone help me this.

Answer (score 1):

The problem was solved, the problem was with my powershell.exe.config file it has incorrect assembly binding. so i ran Get-WFFarm command in powershell ise with WFM Run-AS account. Then it was worked.